# Notification for lifecycleEvent "subscriptionRemoved" not getting triggered by password change on Microsoft Graph API

Tags: javascript, node.js, outlook, notifications, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the Microsoft Graph API to subscribe to notifications for calendar events through Node. Upon reading the documentation for best practices for [Reduce missing subscriptions and notifications for Outlook resources (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks-outlook-authz), it says that:

> Certain events in Outlook can cause a subscription to be removed.
>   These events include:
>
> - User's password has been reset
> - User's device is out of compliance
> - User's account has been revoked
>
> When such an event happens, Outlook sends a special lifecycle
>   notification, subscriptionRemoved.
>
> Outlook also sends another lifecycle notification, missed, if a
>   notification cannot be delivered to an app.
>
> An app subscribing to notifications for Outlook resources, such as
>   message and event, should listen to the subscriptionRemoved and missed
>   signals:
>
> - Upon receiving a subscriptionRemoved notification, the app should
>     recreate the subscription in order to maintain a continuous flow.
> - On receiving a missed notification, the app should resynchronize resource
>     data using Microsoft Graph.
>
> To receive lifecycle notifications, you
>   can use the existing notificationUrl endpoint that already receives
>   resource notifications, or you can register a separate
>   lifecycleNotificationUrl to receive subscriptionRemoved and missed
>   notifications in a separate endpoint.

After I subscribed to a user's calendar events, I get the changes notifications without any issues, but if I change the user's password I should get the lifecycleEvent notification `subscriptionRemoved` like it says above; however, after changing my password about 30 times I never got the notification. What could be the issue here? I couldn't find any more info about how to trigger the notification.

If it helps with anything I'm subscribing to the resource `me/events` with a `changeType: "created,updated,deleted"`.

```
  const subscriptionOptions = {
    changeType: 'created,updated,deleted',
    notificationUrl: `node-service-url/outlook-events/${userId}`,
    resource: 'me/events',
    expirationDateTime: 'someExpirationDateTime',
    clientState: 'someClientState'
  }

  const subscription = await client
    .api('/subscriptions')
    .post(subscriptionOptions)
```

Comment: Don't ever rely on Microsoft notifications and APIs, You need to catch any kind of notification and API call errors. If your API Call responds with 4xx headers then you must do the relevant action according to the error's code and message.

Comment: And be careful about the 'me/events', It only applies to the primary calendar. You must create an extra notification channel for each calendar if there is any.

Comment: I have also noticed exactly same issue shared by @Luis Leon. Can anyone please reply on this.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to listen to lifecycle events, then while creating a subscription, you must specify a notification endpoint using the **lifecycleNotificationUrl** property. If you specify the endpoint, all current and future types of lifecycle notifications will be delivered there. Otherwise, subscriptionRemoved and missed lifecycle notifications will not be delivered. This endpoint can be the same as the notificationUrl or a different one.

In your case, you have not set this property.

Please see official documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks-lifecycle#creating-a-subscription